# Is it possible to filter by a specific field value in Lucene.Net?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

If I have a Lucene index with a field called "ProgrammeTypeId" is it possible to filter the search by specific ProgrammeTypeId values (in a similar way to how you would use a "where" clause in SQL).

Or is Lucene just not intended for that type of search?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, trivially so.

You can pass a `Filter` into search alongside the query.

Alternatively, you can use simple query syntax to combine your filter with the rest of your query:

```
+ProgrammeTypeId:filtervalue +(the rest of the search terms)
```

Or use a [TermQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/da/d32/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_term_query.html), etc.